# custom text css not taking

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get this specific text I downloaded to take in CSS.  I have other fonts that are working.  I had to create an image of the text for the H2 line.  I want p to have the same text.  I would like both of them to work without having to create a png image to have the text I want.  I have the text file uploaded into my public folder.  This is my CSS code:

```
p{
padding-top: 30px;
padding-right: 20px;
font-family: "Paper Daisy";
src: url("img.paperdaisy.ttf");
font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: not clear what you want

Comment: Could you provide a picture of your filetree/file-organization? That might give us a better picture on how to help.

Comment: Do you mean the *font* when you say "text"?

Answer (score 0):

Please create your custom font like this

```
@font-face
{
font-family:yourfontname;
src:url(specify url here) ;
}
```

Then use the font family u specified whereever u want to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd love to recommend using Google Fonts (https://fonts.google.com/). It's super-easy to use them on your website. You can just choose a font and then use it like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Tangerine', serif;
        font-size: 48px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Making the Web Beautiful!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Suddenly Paper Daisy is not avaible on Google Fonts, so you'll have to "instal" it to you website. You can find an answer to "How to do it?" on w3schools.com (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp).

In your CSS file you use:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Paper Daisy;
    src: url(LINKTOFONT.ttf);
}
```

And then in the page you want font to work on:

```
p {
    font-family: Paper Daisy;
}
```